# Google Geocode AJAX - Lookup by Zip Code invalid but returning data

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps-api-3

I'm attempting to query Google Geocode API with the url being

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=00000
```

I'm expecting a result like and receiving this result in my browser and a 3rd party tool like SoapUI.

```
{
 "results" : [],
 "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

However when I query the address using JQuery and Ajax...

```
            var googleAPI = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?";
            var addressCombined = "address=" + jQuery('#ZipCode').val();

            alert(addressCombined);
            $.getJSON(googleAPI,
                {
                    address: addressCombined
                })
                .done(function(data) {
                    alert(googleAPI + addressCombined);
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                   }
                .fail(function(error) {
                    alert("no");
                    console.log("ERROR");
                    console.log(error);
                });
```

I am getting a place in Rhode Island.  Any idea why?
Here are some screenshots

[image: URL to Google]
[image: Result from Google]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
var googleAPI = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?";
var addressCombined = jQuery('#ZipCode').val();

alert(addressCombined);
$.getJSON(googleAPI,
    {
        address: addressCombined
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        alert(googleAPI + addressCombined);
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
       }
    .fail(function(error) {
        alert("no");
        console.log("ERROR");
        console.log(error);
    });
```

No need to add `address` in variable `addressCombined` because we are sending it in ajax with param `address`

**Problem:** there were multiple `address` in **google api url** string `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&address=address=00000` it should be `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&address=00000`

Comment: Same result when I try to query it using JQuery/Ajax.  I also edited the question.  I realized that I wasn't clear with what I was asking.